# JApplet does not showing JPanel with image

Tags: java, japplet

Hello I use a JApplet to show a Jpanel with an image that I get from the network but the applet is loading and not showing the image.

Code:

package com.ntenisot;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Cliente extends JApplet {

JTextField tf;
Lienzo lienzo;
Socket con;
ObjectOutputStream salida;
ObjectInputStream entrada;

public void init(){
    System.out.println("initializing");
    tf = new JTextField(10);
    lienzo=new Lienzo();    
    setSize(1000,1000);
    lienzo.setSize(900,900);
    lienzo.setVisible(true);
    setContentPane(lienzo);

    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setBackground(Color.pink);
    container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    // Text area 1
    String string = "Some text in here, Some text in here, Some text in here";
    JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(string, 10, 15);
    container.add(new JScrollPane(textArea1));
}

public void start() {
    ejecutar();
}

void ejecutar(){
    System.out.println("executing1");

    try{

        con = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5700);
        salida = new ObjectOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        salida.flush();
        entrada = new ObjectInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("executing");
        procesar();


    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }

}   

void procesar() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("processing");

    try{

        while(true){
            ImageIcon img = (ImageIcon) entrada.readObject();
            escribir(img);
        }
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){}

}

void escribir(final ImageIcon img){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    lienzo.pinta(img);
                }

            }
            );

}

class Lienzo extends JPanel{

    ImageIcon img=null ;

    public void pinta(ImageIcon img){
        this.img=img;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

        if(img!=null)   
            img.paintIcon(this,g,10,10);

    }


}   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test your code, but it seems method procesar cannot terminate. Therefore, the method init will also not terminate. I think you could remove the surrounding while (true) loop, as setting the image once is enough.

Comment: Updated the code.. removed ejecutar(); from init and I placed it to start() but still does not display anything!

Comment: why do you need to put while (true) in the method procesar? Are you loading multiple images and making an animation?